# google cluster marker not working using getJSON

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

google cluster marker not working using  getJSON.

i tried to use code at below link: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html

below is my code snippent.

```
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("chart.png",new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

    $.getJSON( "http://example.com/data2.json", function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        var dataDealers = val;
        console.log(val.field_longitude);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataDealers.field_latitude,dataDealers.field_longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: markerImage
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      });
    });
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'm'});
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

content of **data2.json**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Illum Sed Tum Usitas",
        "field_latitude": "-64.404945",
        "field_longitude": "-32.202924",
    },
    {
        "title": "Nobis Oppeto",
        "field_latitude": "17.470493",
        "field_longitude": "47.867077",
    }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maps API & MarkerClusterer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408175/maps-api-markerclusterer)

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON is asynchronous.  You need to add the markers to the clusterer in its callback function.  Your current code adds an empty array to the `markerCluster`, then populates the array when the callback function runs (too late, after it has been added to the clusterer).  One option is to add each marker to the markerCluster as it is created:

```
function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var markers = [];
  var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("chart.png",new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

  // create the clusterer
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {imagePath: 'm'});

  $.getJSON( "http://example.com/data2.json", function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      var dataDealers = val;
      console.log(val.field_longitude);
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataDealers.field_latitude,dataDealers.field_longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        icon: markerImage
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      // add each marker to the clusterer as it is created
      markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
  });
});
```

Comment: hey but i can see it as cluster instead it show as individual marker now

Comment: related to your comment: [Google MarkerClusterer: decluster markers below a certain zoom level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276908/google-markerclusterer-decluster-markers-below-a-certain-zoom-level)

Comment: related to your comment: [Google Map API V3: MarkerClusterer won't break down into markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213030/google-map-api-v3-markerclusterer-wont-break-down-into-markers)

Answer (score 0):

used below code to fix it

```
function initialize() {
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/data2.json", function( data ) {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var markers = [];
        var infowindow;
        var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("chart.png",new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            var dataDealers = val;
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataDealers.field_latitude,dataDealers.field_longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: markerImage
            });



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){
                if(infowindow)infowindow.close();
                infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<h2>"+dataDealers.title+"</h1><p>"+dataDealers.body+"</p>"});
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
            markers.push(marker);

          });
          var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'm'});
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```